# Android minimum required version to open 1MB + files

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

As I've been reading for pas few days, I've realized that android versions below 3 cannot copy files **bigger** than **1MB** from **assets**. For example in my application I'll have a database in assets which will be copied to databases folder on first launch but probably it won't work if my minimum version is below **3** and my db file is bigger than 1MB. I just want to make sure if this is the case so I can push the decision makers to move to higher minimum version( currently minimum is 2.2).

Thanks.

Comment: The target SDK version should correspond to the actual device that you're testing on. It shouldn't be the same as the minimum SDK version.

Comment: @corsair992 sorry mate by target version I meant the minimum version to run the application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing .sqlite database (>1Mb size) in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006588/accessing-sqlite-database-1mb-size-in-android)